# Java: How should look an instanceof method

Tags: java, instanceof

Imagine, I want to write a useless method called: `isInstanceof` that returns a `boolean`.
I was thinking about it. But I do not get out. An `instanceof` has to be used like:

```
[object] instanceof [a classname]

// I was thinking about something like this
public static boolean isInstanceof(Object obj, /*magic for the second param*/)
{
   return obj instanceof /*the magical second param*/
}
```

But how can I make an parameter for `[a classname]`? Is there a way to do this without the method [`isInstance(Class cls)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) from `java.lang.Class`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hehe, yes. Use [isAssignableFrom(Class)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) from `Class`. Not only is it not `isInstance(Class)`, it also matches the way the `instanceof` operator works more closely. :)

Other than that, no, there’s not much you can do without those methods from `Class`.

Comment: Thanks, your last sequence was the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A dynamic version of

```
[object] instanceof [a classname]
```

would be:

```
Class.forName("a classname").isAssignableFrom(object.getClass());
```